# HTML cannot create a new line break

Tags: html, newline

I do not understand why I couldn't insert a new line in this simple html code. I tried both the `<p>` tag and the `<br>` as well as the `<h4>`, etc. I know it must be a simple solution but I can't find it. The last sentence must be under the table. Here is the code:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>
            <span style="color:#FF0000;">Summary</span>
        </h2>
        <h4></h4>
        <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">RESULT</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">QUANTITY</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">PERCENTAGE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>3,69</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>153</td>
                    <td>10,09</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>349</td>
                    <td>23,02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>D</td>
                    <td>393</td>
                    <td>25,92</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>E</td>
                    <td>565</td>
                    <td>37,27</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>SUM</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>1516</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>100</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>I want Newline here!!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid. Learn to use [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) for checking your markup.

Comment: It's your `align=left` on the table.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o0wdj9rc/  just remove align="left"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the attribute align="left" in the table tag

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a `<br />` tag after `<table>`?

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<html><body>
<h2><span style="color:#FF0000;">Summary</span></h2>
<table  border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
<thead><tr><th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">RESULT</th>
<th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">QUANTITY</th>
<th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">PERCENTAGE</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>A</td><td>56</td><td>3,69</td></tr><tr>
<td>B</td><td>153</td><td>10,09</td></tr><tr>
<td>C</td><td>349</td><td>23,02</td></tr><tr>
<td>D</td><td>393</td><td>25,92</td></tr><tr>
<td>E</td><td>565</td><td>37,27</td></tr><tr>
<td><b>SUM</b></td><td><b>1516</b></td><td><b>100</b></td></tr></tbody></table>
<p>I want Newline here!!</p></body></html>
```

Here i removed the `align='left'` attribute from the `table` tag. Now the text is in next new line in end of table.

*Hope this fixed your problem*. If there is some other problem, then comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div style="clear:both;height:1px;"><p>I want Newline here!!</p> </div>` instead.